# Canceling a specific UILocalNotification from the indexPath

Tags: swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uilocalnotification

I have a `tableView` based app with `Core Data`. Each cells are deletable and works pretty cool, thanks to a `NSFetchedResultsController` and their `Delegate` protocol methods. But I want to cancel a specific `UILocalNotification` instances while a specific cell is deleted. A `Core Data` contains all of the information of `UILocalNotification` and an `userInfo` included. I'm really stopped here. Can anybody tell me? If it's possible or I should use a `NSUserDefaults` instead of a `Core Data`?

Here's what I've done. It's seems to works properly, but I don't know it's correctly or not

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


if editingStyle == .Delete {

            let delete = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? NSManagedObject
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

            for notification in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications! {
                if (notification.userInfo!["givenName"] as? String == cell?.textLabel?.text) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
                break
               }
            }
            self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(delete!)  // Delete Action

            do {
            // Save Action
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()  // Save Action
            } catch { // An Error 
          }
        }
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: It's possible. Show your code. Explain what it does wrong.

Comment: Dear @Wain! I've edited my question. And I've added an example codes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it actually works, any problem is a design issue which has been discussed many times before

Comment: So it's correctly solution? Thanks

Comment: it works. you shouldn't take the string from the cell, it should come from your data model, but that's a different issue